# Media files not showing up after deployment

Tags: django, deployment

So I just finished deploying a django app to the internet and for some reason media files won't show up.
[here's the link I followed](https://gist.github.com/bradtraversy/cfa565b879ff1458dba08f423cb01d71)

everything works perfectly fine but medias and the weird thing is the media does exist at the exact path it should come from but it won't show up.

Comment: Did you check permissions?

Comment: @farooq no, sry but do you mind explaining this to me? its my first time deploying a website.

Answer (score 0):

try to change `root` to `alias` in your nginx setup and after `service nginx restart`